# Defining a random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$ on a finite number of points.

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I am trying to define a random variable with mean 0 and variance 1. I want to select equidistant points on the real line, and assign probabilities to each of them so that the above conditions are satisfied.

1. When I do it on three points, I choose $(-1,1/2), (0,0), (1,1/2)$, where $(a,b)$ denotes point $a$ with probability $b$. Is it okay to assign $0$ probability to a point? This is the only way that I am able to get a mean of $0$ and a variance of $1$.
2. How do I do it on 4 points? When I try to do it on the points $-3,-1,1,3$, the only possibility I'm able to come up with is assigning the probability $1/2$ to $-1,1$, and $0$ to $-3,3$. I would prefer to assign non-zero weights to all points.

Comment: Your task is somewhat easier if you shoot for a 2 point solution, because when you set up the algebra you have the same number of unknowns and equations.  Or, because it's easier to guess the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your support may constrain your results. Remember $\textrm{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2] - (\mathbb E[X])^2$ and here $\mathbb E[X]=0$ so you want $\mathbb E[X^2]=1$.

So with $\{-1,0,+1\}$ and a mean of $0$, you are going to find it impossible to get the variance over $1$, and it is only possible to get $1$ putting all the probability at $-1$ and $+1$, reducing to two points.

But there are many other three-point examples which would work, such as

- support on $\{-2,0,+2\}$ with $\mathbb P(X=-2)=\frac18$, $\mathbb P(X=0)=\frac34$, $\mathbb P(X=+2)=\frac18$

Similarly  with $\{-3,-1,+1,+3\}$ and a mean of $0$, you are going to find it impossible to get the variance under $1$, and it is only possible to get $1$ putting all the probability at $-1$ and $+1$, reducing to two points.

But there are many other four-point examples which would work, such as

- support on $\{-1,0,+1,+2\}$ with $\mathbb P(X=-1)=\frac38$, $\mathbb P(X=0)=\frac38$, $\mathbb P(X=+1)=\frac18$, $\mathbb P(X=+2)=\frac18$

Comment: Can I not "reduce it to two points"? Is it illegal to assign a 0 probability to one point, if I am trying to study a random variable over three points?

Comment: You can do what you want.  It is up to you whether "a random variable over three points" would include "a random variable over two points" for your purposes.  My aim was to show that it is not necessary to go down to two even with equidistant points on the real line.

Comment: The reason I ask is that I'm trying to solve a research problem in which I'm trying to construct a random variable on 4 points with these properties. All my calculations work out only when I assign a probability of 0 to one of the points, and do not work out when I assign non-zero probabilities to all points. This has been bugging me. Hence, I want to make sure that I'm not doing something clearly stupid.

Comment: My final example is one of many with four points each having positive probability.  There are others such as the symmetric $\mathbb P(X=-\frac32)=\frac3{16}$, $\mathbb P(X=-\frac12)=\frac5{16}$, $\mathbb P(X=+\frac12)=\frac5{16}$, $\mathbb P(X=+\frac32)=\frac3{16}$ and many more asymmetric examples